# Solve differential equation in Python when I don't know the derivative analytically

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations, numba

I'm trying to solve a first-order ODE in Python:

[image: http://www.sciweavers.org/upload/Tex2Img_1510767778/render.png]

where Gamma and u are square matrices.
I don't explicitly know u(t) at all times, but I do know it at discrete timesteps from doing an earlier calculation.

Every example I found of Python's solvers online (e.g. [this one](http://www.physics.nyu.edu/pine/pymanual/html/chap9/chap9_scipy.html#solving-odes) for `scipy.integrate.odeint` and `scipy.integrate.ode`) know the expression for the derivative analytically as a function of time.

Is there a way to call these (or other differential equation solvers) without knowing an analytic expression for the derivative?

For now, I've written my own Runge-Kutta solver and jitted it with `numba`.

Comment: *"For now, I've written my own Runge-Kutta solver and jitted it with numba."*  That's great, but it doesn't really tell us how you solved the problem of u(t) being known only at discrete points.  Did you interpolate?  If so, what interpolation did you use?  Piecewise constant?  Linear interpolation?  Higher order interpolation?

Comment: I should have specified: I didn't interpolate at all -- I used RK4 with the minimum step size equivalent to my timestep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of the SciPy [interpolation methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html), such as [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d), to create a callable function based on your discrete data, and pass it to `odeint`. Cubic spline interpolation,

```
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
```

should be good enough.

Comment: I guess I'd use `initerp2d`, since I'm dealing with matrices. I'm not sure if the overhead of interpolation will be too high. I'll give it a try.

Comment: 2d refers to the dimension of domain (independent variable). When solving an ODE system, you have a matrix-valued function of 1d argument, which  `interp1d` can handle. The overhead will be negligible if you use linear interpolation.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to call these (or other differential equation solvers) without knowing an analytic expression for the derivative?

Yes, none of the solvers you mentioned (nor most other solvers) require an analytic expression for the derivative. Instead they call a function you supply that has to evaluate the derivative for a given time and state. So, your code would roughly look something like:

```
def my_derivative(time,flat_Gamma):
    Gamma = flat_Gamma.reshape(dim_1,dim_2)
    u = get_u_from_time(time)
    dGamma_dt = u.dot(Gamma)
    return dGamma_dt.flatten()

from scipy.integrate import ode
my_integrator = ode(my_derivative)
…
```

The difficulty in your situation is rather that you have to ensure that `get_u_from_time` provides an appropriate result for every time with which it is called. Probably the most robust and easy solution is to use interpolation (see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47314306/2127008)).

You can also try to match your integration steps to the data you have, but at least for `scipy.integrate.odeint` and `scipy.integrate.ode` this will be very tedious as all the integrators use internal steps that are inconvenient for this purpose. For example, [the fifth-order Dormand–Prince method (DoPri5)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormand%E2%80%93Prince_method) uses internal steps of 1/5, 3/10, 4/5, 8/9, and 1. This means that if you have temporally equidistant data for `u`, you would need 90 data points for each integration step (as 1/90 is the greatest common divisor of the internal steps). The only integrator that could make this remotely feasible is the [Bogacki–Shampine integrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogacki%E2%80%93Shampine_method) (RK23) from [`cipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) with internal steps of 1/2, 3/4, and 1.